# Set Opacity of a Form Panel

Tags: extjs, extjs4

I have a `form panel`, and i need to set it's background to `Semi-Transparent`. How could i do this ? (for example to set the `opacity 0.5`)

Answer (score 1):

**For an Element:**

Assuming html fragment:

```
<div id="div1">
    <form id="form1" >
       <b>Name:</b><input type="text" name="Bla" value="data"/>
    </form>
</div>
```

ExtJS code:

```
var div1 = Ext.get("div1");
div1.setOpacity(.5);
```

**For a Panel**

Assuming you have a Ext.form.Panel defined:

```
 var panel1 =  Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', { .... }
```

Use the Ext.Shadow class:

```
 var shad =  new Ext.Shadow( panel1);
 shad.setOpacity(.5);
```

References:
http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.Shadow-method-constructor